# Unable to do only one item expandable list view in drawer

Tags: android

In my app I want an expandable list view, only one item and expandable list item comes from mysql database, with a click on the item it opens a fragment. I have searched many answers, but nothing work for me, I want when clicking on a category the list shows which data comes from a database. And when clicking on any item it works like a drawer item click.

[image]
I want this category as expandable listview.

> drawer.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/wishlist"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_wishlist"
        android:title="Wish List" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_category"
        android:title="Category"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_shopping_basket"
        android:title="Your Orders" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_shopping_cart"
        android:title="Your Cart" />
</group>

<item android:title="Activity">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/account"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_person"
            android:title="Your Account" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

> activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_drawer" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_height"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/ic_menu_expand"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is library named [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).
It is really simple to use and it can satisfy your expectations.

Comment: thanks...I got some idea for some other app. I use this on other app. But I don't want to use this app.